# Increase bootstrap grid width beyond 1170px

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a way to increase the width of the Bootstrap 3 grid to beyond 1170? My users often use devices that support 1920 x 1080 resolution. I want to maintain the responsiveness (in case the window is not maximized) but whenever the window is > 1600px in width, I want the grid system to be as wide as 1600px.

Is there a way to add another "step" to the grid system for windows wider than 1600px? Preferably without using LESS, just by adding some Custom CSS to override original Bootstrap rules?

Answer (score 3):

Allow me to answer the question myself. I needed to change my search keywords to find the answer. It was mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9256) on Bootstrap's GitHub issue tracker (last comment). It is a CSS file called [BootstrapXL](https://github.com/marcvannieuwenhuijzen/BootstrapXL/blob/master/BootstrapXL.css) which basically adds a new "x-large" grid level to Bootstrap 3 for devices beyond 1600 px in width (i.e. Full HD monitors with the window maximized).